# What HTML markup is appropriate for the transcription of an interview?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I am asking for an advice on what kind of markup should be used to mark up an *interview type of content* in HTML as a transcribed interview in a cleanest and semantically most sensible way?

Preferably I would like something that would be valid HTML5, but that is not a hard requirement.

(My initial impulse was to use `<dl>`, `<dt>` and `<dd>` tags, but that does not seem right for some reason)

Ps - I am just on the outlook for the good clean way to generally represent conversation type content in HTML.

Someone posted a suggestion to use `<dialog>` tag, but that has been banned by WHATWG and their official suggestion for replacement is to use a series of `<p>` tags: It seems that the `<dialog>` tag has been banned from HTML5 and no sensible replacement has been proposed. The spec itself says that one should mark up the conversation as a series of `p` tags: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#conversations

Comment: 'banned' is putting it a bit strongly. 'dialog' was dropped from HTML5, IIRC, because the browser makers baulked at the work involved in adding an element that to them didn't seem to do anything. Personally, I find all the current options unsatisfactory.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd use `dl` or (`p` and `abbr`) combination.

Here, on SO markup like this:

```
<p><abbr title="Anakin Skywalker">AS</abbr>: 
   Master Norris, do you really parse HTML with regex?</p>
<p><abbr title="Chuck Norris">CN</abbr>: 
   Not anymore… I have already parsed it all.</p>
```

becomes:

---

AS: Master Norris, do you really parse HTML with regex?

CN: Not anymore… I have already parsed it all.

---

The CSS styles are poor, but HTML without stylesheets looks good and the screen readers should do their job right.

#### The ideal markup

The ideal markup would allow to easily extract just:

- the questions
- or the answers

So `dl` like structure would be fine, or even better:

```
<dialogue>
   <which>AS</which>
   <what>Master Norris, do you really parse HTML with regex?</what>
   <which>AS</which>
   <what>Not anymore… I have already parsed it all.</what>
</dialogue>
```

Which is exactly the same structure as `dl`, `dt` and `dd`.

The even better:

```
<interview>
   <question>
       <which>AS</which>
       <what>Master Norris, do you really parse HTML with regex?</what>
   </question>
   <answer>
       <which>CN</which>
       <what>Not anymore… I have already parsed it all.</what>
   </answer>
</interview>
```

Unfortunately, there is no valid markup in HTML for this :)

Comment: I give you +1 for the effort you put into this answer, although most of it is more of a wishful thinking sort.

And for the record - I am starting to warm up to the proposal of marking up conversations as series of `<p>` tags. Slapping some classes on them should be enough to distinguish questions from answers.
Your proposal for using `<abbr>` for abbreviated names is also a nice one.

Comment: "Slapping some classes on them should be enough to distinguish questions from answers."

What about screen readers?

Comment: [WhatWG's suggestion](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/links.html#conversations) is stupid IMO. A conversation is a bit more, structurally, than a series of paragraphs and "slapping some classes on them" does nothing to define the structure.